# PHP Dropdown - Inserting Records from Multi Dependent Dropdown to MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Good Day! StackOverFlow Community
I have the below-mentioned code where Multi-Dependent Dropdown shows up with data. When I try to insert in MYSQL DB, only ID is inserted not the name whereas I am inserting the name
I surely am making mistake somewhere, need your precious guidance

Thanks

```
<?php
require_once ("DBController.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
$query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
$countryResult = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
?>
<html>
<head>
<TITLE>Dynamically Load Dependent Dropdown on Multi-Select using PHP and
    jQuery</TITLE>


<head>
<style>
body {
    width: 610px;
    font-family: calibri;
}

.frmDronpDown {
    border: 1px solid #7ddaff;
    background-color: #C8EEFD;
    margin: 2px 0px;
    padding: 40px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.demoInputBox {
    padding: 10px;
    border: #bdbdbd 1px solid;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 50%;
}

.row {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function getState() {
        var str='';
        var val=document.getElementById('country-list');
        for (i=0;i< val.length;i++) { 
            if(val[i].selected){
                str += val[i].value + ','; 
            }
        }         
        var str=str.slice(0,str.length -1);
        
    $.ajax({          
            type: "GET",
            url: "get_state.php",
            data:'country_id='+str,
            success: function(data){
                $("#state-list").html(data);
            }
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="form-group" style="font-family:arial;">
                    <label for="landnumber">Land Number:</label><b><label style="float:right;">رمز الأرض</b></label>
                    <select dir="rtl" lang="ar" id='landnumber' name='landnumber' class="form-control" required>
                                <option disabled selected>-- رمز الأرض --</option>
                    
                    <?php
        include "connect.php";  // Using database connection file here
        $records = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT landnumber From landnumbers");  // Use select query here 

        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
        {
            echo "<option value='". $data['landnumber'] ."'>" .$data['landnumber'] ."</option>";  // displaying data in option menu
        }   
    ?>  
</select>

                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <form method="post" action="">
    <div class="frmDronpDown">
        <div class="row">
            <label>Categories - التصنيفات </label><br /> <select name="country[]"
                id="country-list" class="demoInputBox"
                onChange="getState();" multiple size=4>
                <option value="">Select Categories</option>
<?php
foreach ($countryResult as $country) {
    ?>
<option value="<?php echo $country["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $country["name"]; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label>Activities - الأنشطة</label><br /> <select name="state[]"
                id="state-list" class="demoInputBox" multiple size=5>
                <option value="">الأنشطة</option>
            </select>
        </div>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="action" class="btn btn-info" value="Insert" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
require('connect.php');
        $state_string = implode(', ', $_POST['country']);
        $sql = '
            INSERT INTO
                `chosen_activities` (
                 `name`
                )
            VALUES (
                "'. $state_string .'"
            )';
        mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    }
?>
```

**This below line of code inserts only ID not the name, I want to insert name**

```
 <option value="<?php echo $country["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $country["name"]; ?></option>
```

Thanks

**What I have Tried**

```
 <option value="<?php echo $country["name"]; ?>"><?php echo $country["name"]; ?></option>
```

I have changed id to name but then other dropdown doesn't populate as it is populating by ID only. You can see AJAX above bringing get_state

Answer (score 0):

In a `select` input, the value of the selected option is submitted to the backend on form submit.

So if you want to submit the name instead of id you just have to change the values of the `options`.

```
<option value="<?php echo $country["name"]; ?>"><?php echo $country["name"]; ?></option>
```

This will submit the name.

Or else you can submit the ID and run a separate SQL query on PHP side to get the name.

```
<option value="<?php echo $country["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $country["name"]; ?></option>
```

Then you can access the variable in $_POST['country-list'] and run a select query to get the name from the database.

Comment: i already know this and this works too but problem is this dropdown calls another dropdown on basis of ID when I replace id by name, it doesn't populate another dropdown, which is shown by previous one's id you can see above in ajax I mentioned already the get_state
Thanks

Comment: To accomplish this you can do 2 things. 1. Have the ID in the value attribute and get the name based on the ID in your PHP by running a select query based on the ID you submitted.  
2. Have something like ``ID-NAME`` in your value attribute and split the array using ``-`` in the javascript before you fire the other AJAX call. (I prefer the 1st option)

Comment: So, you mean to say I use here  <option value="<?php echo $country["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $country["name"]; ?></option> and then select name where id is this.. right ... problem is names are coming correct in other dropdown but inserting is only done for id... or you are saying I call another dropdowbn by select query you mentioned?

Comment: So  you are using ``<option value="<?php echo $country["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $country["name"]; ?></option>`` and when you submit the form you get the ``ID`` in PHP payload. When you receive the id, run a select query to get the name associated with the id. In this way, you do not need to change the javascript for other select as you haven't changed anything in your HTML and Javascript.

Comment: Ahh I got it so after getting ID I should do something like get name where id is this and store name in abc suppose and insert this abc in db Right?

Comment: It will surely work Kindly please make this as final answer below. I will up vote and mark as complete. Thanks

Comment: Yes- thats correct...when you get the Id you can run a select query to get the name.

Comment: Thanks. Can you post the same as answer so I will mark it? or above one you mentioned if you can edit and add more...

Answer (score 0):

From your information, I get that you are trying to insert a name instead of an ID,
I hope you are using ID as int in mysql corresponding table, Here you have to know  Int only allow numbers to insert, So you have to create a separate column for name field or you have to change the data type of the Id column to allow insert.

For good Practices your multi-dependent dropdown **keeps id as foreign key**

Comment: I already have ID and name as two separate columns and I am inserting data in name not ID but it is still inserting in ID
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

change the value in $country['name']

```
 <option value="<?php echo $country["name"]; ?>"><?php echo $country["name"]; ?></option>
```

Comment: i already know this and this works too but problem is this dropdown calls another dropdown on basis of ID when I replace id by name, it doesn't populate another dropdown, which is shown by previous one's id you can see above in ajax I mentioned already the get_state
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, this is how I did that keeping ID same above in drop down output and not modifying anything else

```
 if (isset($_REQUEST['country'])) {
    $i=implode(',', $_REQUEST['country']);
      $query = "SELECT name FROM categories where id IN ($i)";
$result = $db->query($query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row["name"]."<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$db->close();
 }
```

Thanks to all those who helped ...

Comment: Perhaps you could format your code according to some indentantion rules?